# How to get ViewHolder of specific item in android leanback component?

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I am using android leanback component ArrayObjectAdapter with custom Presenter to create a row of elements. I want to get reference to one of the item in that row to do some ui operation. Is there any way to do this ?

```
private fun createRows(movieResponse: MovieResponse) {
    val cardPresenter = CardPresenter()
    val listRowAdapter = ArrayObjectAdapter(cardPresenter)
    movieResponse.movieList.forEach {
        listRowAdapter.add(it)
    }

    val rowsAdapter = ArrayObjectAdapter(ListRowPresenter())
    rowsAdapter.add(ListRow(listRowAdapter))

    adapter = rowsAdapter
}
```

I am looking for something similar to what we have in recyclerview

```
myRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(pos);
```